# Why do Android alarms fire at the same time?

Tags: java, android, timer, alarm

Below is a pretty simple method that takes a Date and an id for an alarm to be fired which starts a countdown. For some reason I don't understand, if I call it once with one date and id 0 and call it again with another date and id 1 (i.e., two different countdowns), Android will fire both alarms at the same time (specifically the first date passed with id 0) so both countdowns start at the same time.

Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
public void setCountdownAlarm(Date fireTime, int id)
{
    // startCountdown will be called at fireTime
    BroadcastReceiver startCountdown = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override public void onReceive( Context context, Intent theIntent )
        {
            countdownTimer = new Timer();
            countdownTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    onSecondTick(showtime);
                }
            }, 0, 100); // call every 10th of a second
        }
    };

    this.registerReceiver( startCountdown, new IntentFilter("com.counter.app.CountActivity.COUNT") );
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.counter.app.CountActivity.COUNT");
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, id, intent, 0 );
    AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService( Context.ALARM_SERVICE ));

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
        manager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime.getTime(), pintent);
    else
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime.getTime(), pintent);
}
```

Editing to say that when I waited for the second alarm to fire, Android actually calls startCountdown twice -- once again for each alarm. Help!

Comment: How far apart are the alarm times? Android will batch alarms by default to save battery power.

Comment: I've seen it happen when the alarms are only 2 minutes apart.

Comment: I found that it works correctly (both alarms fire at the right times) if I also specify a unique filter for each one. That is, instead of "com.counter.app.CountActivity.COUNT" I used "com.counter.app.CountActivity.COUNT" + id. I can't believe this is the correct way to do it, but I can't figure out the better alternative.

Comment: For those who stumbled upon this because they made the same stupid mistake, my problem was that I registered the BroadcastReceiver each time I called setCountdownAlarm. The BroadcastReceiver should only be registered once!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I did wrong. As explained in answers to similar questions, the second parameter of PendingIntent.getBroadcast (requestCode) must be unique if you want to get a unique pending intent. I took care of that by passing "id".

The second problem was that I registered the BroadcastReceiver each time I called setCountdownAlarm. The BroadcastReceiver should only be registered once, typically in the onCreate method of the activity.